# Initialize a subobject of an object in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Let we have an object `x` of class `A` (which may have "private" fields, which I do not know) and I am creating a class `B`:

```
class B(A):
    # ...
```

Now I want to create an object `y` of class `B`, whose `A` part is equal to `x`.

How to do this in Python (both 2.x and 3.x)?

Comment: Do you know the attributes which comprise the parts of `x` you want to copy to `y`?

Comment: @StephenRauch The problem is that I do not know them, or worse these attributes may change in a future version of `A`

Comment: There is no direct way to do this with Python that I am aware of.  There are various ways to this could be done, but it will depend heavily on how `A` and `B` are implemented.

Comment: If you want a `B` object that has all the private field values of the `A` object, you can do: `b.__dict__.update(a.__dict__)`. The object `a` itself cannot be magically 'wrapped' by `b`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood well, but I think you need this in the `class B`:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, variable):
        self.variable = variable

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Everytime you instantiate a new object from B, it will initialize all attributes in `A.__init__` method. If you need the list of attributes:

```
y = B(variable="123...")
attrs = y.__dict__.keys()
```

Comment: `x` object is already present. I cannot create it as you suggest